# directory is not empty: brownie

Tags: error, brownie

I'm getting this error when I try to setup a brownie project using brownie init. I initially installed brownie using pip install eth-brownie in the virtual environment. The folder `.venv` is present because of that. Not sure if I'm getting error because of .venv folder. Any suggestions how to work around this problem? Thank you in advance!!

```sh
Brownie v1.17.0 - Python development framework for Ethereum

  File "brownie/_cli/__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "brownie/_cli/init.py", line 31, in main
    path = project.new(args["<path>"] or ".", args["--force"], args["--force"])
  File "brownie/project/main.py", line 584, in new
    raise FileExistsError(f"Directory is not empty: {project_path}")
FileExistsError: Directory is not empty: /Users/patrick/demos/contracts
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to work when I'm not using virtual environment but when I check brownie documentation they mention it is recommended to setup venv and then use pip to install eth-brownie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because there is stuff in your directory already.

You can either:

### Force create the directory

```sh
brownie init --force
```

Which will create the brownie sample directory alongside your existing code/contracts/`.venv` file.

### Remove everything in that directory

```sh
rm -rf *
brownie init
```

### Create a new folder with your brownie project

```sh
mkdir brownie_project
cd brownie_project
brownie init
```

Answer (score 2):

there might be two things.

1. .hypothesis
2. you might have something inside the folder

So we need to remove those things

> rm *       ( Then press A to remove all)

then run

> Brownie init

if .hypothesis file comes again then remove everything from the file then run the following command..

> Brownie init --force

Answer (score 0):

```
brownie init --force
```

works, but I wonder what's the problem with this .hypothesis?
what is this lib for?

Comment: Hi VladislavLenskii! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! To answer and old question  you have to provide more content than existing answers.